# Twilio whatapp bot not responding to keywords

Tags: python, flask, twilio, chatbot

I am trying to build a whatsapp bot on Twilio following the Twilio tutorial.

I have written the flask program to create a test bot:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/bot', methods=['POST'])
def bot():
    incoming_msg = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    responded = False
    if 'quote' in incoming_msg:
        # return a quote
        r = requests.get('https://api.quotable.io/random')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            data = r.json()
            quote = f'{data["content"]} ({data["author"]})'
        else:
            quote = 'I could not retrieve a quote at this time, sorry.'
        msg.body(quote)
        responded = True
    if 'cat' in incoming_msg:
        # return a cat pic
        msg.media('https://cataas.com/cat')
        responded = True
    if not responded:
        msg.body('I only know about famous quotes and cats, sorry!')
    return str(resp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The app is running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

When I click this link this is what I see

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Installed and run ngrok. I pasted the url under forwarding (there are two I copied the first), pasted this url to my Twilio sandbox (when a message comes in URL) and added /bot to the path.

However when I try and type cat on whatsapp (I have added my whatsapp number to my sandbox) I do not get a response (from my understanding I should be getting a picture of a cat if I type the keyword cat).

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the same code here from the blog here (is this the blog you used), [Build a WhatsApp Chatbot With Python, Flask and Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-a-whatsapp-chatbot-with-python-flask-and-twilio), and updated the WhatsApp sandbox [When A Message Comes In](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/sandbox) URL to point to the Ngrok URL which exposes it to the Internet and it works.

Can you check your [Twilio Debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger?quickDate=24), to see if there were any errors?

You cannot use your web browser to visit the Flask URL, since it is expecting an HTTP POST and your browser is using an HTTP GET. You can use a tool like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to do a POST to your URL, and see what response you get.

You should get this response when visit the URL and sending in the Body POST parameter of cat.

[image]

You could also check the Ngrok debug URL, http://127.0.0.1:4040/, to see what you are getting from Twilio when you send an inbound WhatsApp sandbox message, and debug from there.

Comment: Got it, turns out I was adding http instead of the https url